# How to send a handled exception to HockeyApp SDK in XAMARIN android app?

Tags: xamarin, exception, hockeyapp

Hi guys is this possible to send a handled exception to HockeyApp SDK using Xamarin android ?

I am getting unhandled  exceptions in HockeyApp SDK .

Can any one suggest some way to this problem.

the below code is one of my experiment. This is also not working

```
try
            {
                MetricsManager.Register(Application.Context, Application, "aca46d1941bd4891bb1ce2ab770e28a8");

                MetricsManager.EnableUserMetrics();
                int a = 10;
                int b = a / 0;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MetricsManager.TrackEvent(ex.ToString());
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you might have seen how to do [custom logging in hockey app](https://www.devprotocol.com/add-custom-logging-to-your-xamarin-app/) the same can be done for handled exceptions, Something like this:

```
catch(Exception ex) {
 MetricsManager.TrackEvent(ex.Message);
 MetricsManager.TrackEvent(ex.Stacktrace);
 }
```

Also, I would suggest you check this out [MSDN on HockeyApp in XF](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/raw-tech/HockeyApp-in-XamarinForms)

Good luck!

In case of queries revert.

Comment: I have tried it but it is not working. I can see the unhandled exceptions but it not registering the events.NOt able to see the handled exceptions

Answer (score 1):

HockeyApp does not support handled exceptions. If you are looking for handled exceptions support and specifically with Xamarin, take a look at HockeyApp's successor product App Center: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/crashes/xamarin#handled-errors-in-xamarin

Comment: My application is not deployed on AppCenter. So that i am only able to collect the report from HockeyApp .